# jQuery empty() callback not being fired

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm emptying an element of all children, then applying an element with the same class but within separate element.

The callback on this `empty()` function isn't firing. Am I missing something with this class/callback issue?

```
$('.commentsButton').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
if ('.openComments').length) {
    $(this).closest('.box').removeClass(openComments);

    $('.commentsBox').empty(function(){
            $(this).closest('.box').find('.commentsBox').load('url.com');
            $(this).closest('.box').addClass(openComments);
        });
} else {
        $(this).closest('.box').find('.commentsBox').load('url.com');
        $(this).closest('.box').addClass(openComments);
    }
});

<div class="box">
  <a class="commentsButton" href="#"></a>
   <div class="commentsBox"></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <a class="commentsButton" href="#"></a>
   <div class="commentsBox"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you read the documentation on http://api.jquery.com/empty/, it says: 'This function does not accept any arguments'.

Comment: @putvande Crap. Missed that part... Is there any way to perform the above?

Comment: empty() is a synchronous method, so you don't need a callback.

Comment: Can you not just say `$('.commentsBox').closest('.box').find('.commentsBox').load('url.com');$('.commentsBox').closest('.box').addClass(openComments);`?

Comment: And what's up with `.closest('.box').find('.commentsBox')`? Wouldn't that pretty much be the same selector as `this` ?

Comment: @putvande the reason I'm emptying the element first is because I'm calling a Disqus comments box. Only one can be on any loaded page at a time.

Comment: @adeneo the function needs to find the specific `box` that it was clicked within. Updated to show that.

Comment: I sort of got that, but inside the callback for `empty` (which of course doesn't exist) `this` would be `.commentsBox`, and closest `box` and then `commentsBox` would be the exact same selector. But, never mind that, as it won't work like that anyway !

Comment: Good thinking. I chose a different answer based on crossing my fingers and hoping for the sequential loading. Still have an issue with Wordpress not always loading `comments_template` when loaded via Ajax, but that's for a new question. Thanks for all the input everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.commentsButton').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.box').removeClass('openComments');
    $('.commentsBox').empty();
    $(this).closest('.box').addClass('openComments')
           .find('.commentsBox').load('url.com');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

just call the empty function without any parameter and then do whatever you like.

```
$('.commentsBox').empty();
$('.commentsBox').each(function(){
      $(this).closest('.box').find('.commentsBox').load('url.com');
      $(this).closest('.box').addClass(openComments);
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't this load each `.commentsBox` all at the same time?