# Why I can't add code after JQuery .empty()?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to remove all the child nodes of my structure before adding others children.

I have read here [jQuery empty() callback not being fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934491/jquery-empty-callback-not-being-fired) that I could do `.empty()` and then my code to the bottom.

So here I reproduced my use case

```js
//document.getElementById("labelEnv").innerHTML ="";

$("#labelEnv").empty()

$("<input type='text' class='input-field env' value='I wont be added'/>").insertBefore($('.addEnv'));
```

```css
.form-style-2{
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 10px 10px 2px 10px;
  font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: rgba(blue, 0.8);
}
.form-style-2-heading{
  color:black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.form-style-2 label{
  display:table;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.form-style-2 label > span{
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 5px;
  width:25%;
  display: table-cell;
}
.form-style-2 span.required{
  color:red;
}

.form-style-2 a{
  display: block;
}
.form-style-2 input.input-field {
  border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 4px;
  outline: medium none;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 31%;
}
.form-style-2 input.env, input.vol{
  width: 100% !important;
}
.form-style-2 input.nameModif{
  width: 50% !important;
}


.form-style-2 .input-field:focus{
  border: 1px solid #0C0;
}
.form-style-2 input.saveModif{
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #DADADA;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.form-style-2 input.saveModif:hover{
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
}

.form-style-2 input.cancelModif{
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #DADADA;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.form-style-2 input.cancelModif:hover{
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divCodeContainer">
        <div class="form-style-2">
          <div class="form-style-2-heading"></div>
          <form action="" method="post">
            <label>
              <span>Container name
                <span class="required">*</span>
              </span>
              <input type="text" class="input-field nameModif" value="" />
            </label>
            <label id="labelEnv">
              <span>Environment
              </span>
              <input type="text" class="input-field env" value="replace me" />
              <a class="addEnv" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
            </label>
            <label id="labelVol">
              <span>Volumes
              </span>
              <input type="text" class="input-field vol" value="replace me" />
              <a class="addVol" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
            </label>
            <label>
              <span>&nbsp;</span>
              <input class="saveModif" type="button" value="Save" />
              <input class="cancelModif" type="button" value="Cancel" />
            </label>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

if you comments the `$("#labelEnv").empty()` my `input` is added, so how should I modify my code to empty before adding ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Behavior is expected, as the element `.addEnv` is child of `#labelEnv`, once you use `.empty()` element doesn't exists thus its not inserted.

```js
$("#labelEnv :not(.addEnv)").remove();
$("<input type='text' class='input-field env' value='I wont be added'/>").insertBefore($('.addEnv'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="labelEnv">
              <span>Environment              </span>
              <input type="text" class="input-field env" value="replace me" />
              <a class="addEnv" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
  </label>
```

Comment: Oh I didn't noticed that... you have an idea how I could remove the child except `.addEnv` ?

Comment: @Jerome, I have added a sample snippet hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the snippet, I didn't knew this kind of selector, thank you so much